# Cannot ping RRAS Client from RRAS server

Tags: windows, vpn, rras

I have recently created an RRAS pptp connection for an outside network. The RRAS client connects fine and can ping the RRAS server and every device on the RRAS servers local network. The RRAS server cannot ping the remote pptp client nor can any device on the RRAS servers local network. RRAS is configured to be within the same subnet as the RRAS servers local network. On connection it pulls from a static IP pool.
Any help is truly appreciated

Comment: Why does the server need to be able to ping the client?

Comment: On my home network I host a server 2008r2 member server with RRAS and the remote device can share folders and act as a member on the RRAS local network.I can ping any Remote client from any Local client. On my work network I do not have that sharing compatibility and i was just using ping to verify connection but it seems there is an issue somewhere.